# Constant that changes it's value in Ada

Tags: constants, ada

Can something that knows the adress of a constant changes it or Ada is secured about that?

I am currently working on a big project and i can't read all the code of the project. But I have to Debug some part of it. And i have strange trouble. Indeed, I have changed the declaration of a variable like that 
`My_Var : constant Integer :=1;` in my package (let's call it `My_Package`)
Then some stuff is done on my variable in the project (black box) 
And when I execute that code at the end,

`My_Package.My_Var<=0` it returns `True`

**My question is**, can something that knows the adress of my constant changes it or ada is secured about that?

PS: I did a `(gdb) watch My_Package.My_Var` and nothing stopped the program until i get my error after the `if My_Package.My_Var<=0`

PS PS: I also tried to change my constant in `function` returning a constant value and the bug gone with that (but didn't helped me to see where the variable gets modified)
Hope you can help me.

Thanks

Comment: A constant can be mapped (with an address aspect) to a read-only hardware port. Such a constant should usually be marked volatile, so it is re-read (to observe any changes in the hardware state). This often applies to embedded processor (MCU) targets ... what target system are you dealing with?

Comment: I'm working on a code that should work on embedded x86 but I must use it Linux x86. 
So that might be the behave I had (address of hard ware not corresponding on Linux compilation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that knows the address of a constant may be able to change it.  The exceptions are if the constant is stored in an (EP)ROM or if the compiler has conspired with the operating system to put it in a read-only section of the executable.

In general Ada allows you to work around all the safeties, if you really care enough to do the work needed.